# How to get the "heartbeat" effect on focused modal window?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-modal

Bootstrap has [documentation about a "static" modal](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/components/modal/#static-backdrop), one that doesn't close when clicked outside. If you try to click outside of it in their demo, it animates with a little "heartbeat" (or how do you call it) effect that indicates it needs attention.

But when I copy their exact HTML code from the sample, it doesn't do the animation. Fiddle for that available here:
https://jsfiddle.net/5jhuwgnd/

Obviously something is missing here, and it seems undocumented. And it can't be a HTML attribute since I do have the HTML sample... Is it an extra JS plugin that needs to be included, or what?

---

(since Stackoverflow doesn't allow JS Fiddle links without code, here it is, although I don't think it's that relevant to have it here)

```
<!-- Button trigger modal -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#staticBackdrop">
  Launch static backdrop modal
</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="staticBackdrop" data-backdrop="static" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="staticBackdropLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="staticBackdropLabel">Modal title</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        ...
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Understood</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fiddle is missing the javascript that creates the animation. Adding the [latest javascript](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js) works.

When looking at the source, `modal.js` file adds the class `modal-static` to the modal.

```js
  _triggerBackdropTransition() {
    if (this._config.backdrop === 'static') {
      const hideEventPrevented = $.Event(Event.HIDE_PREVENTED)

      $(this._element).trigger(hideEventPrevented)
      if (hideEventPrevented.defaultPrevented) {
        return
      }

      this._element.classList.add(ClassName.STATIC)

      const modalTransitionDuration = Util.getTransitionDurationFromElement(this._element)

      $(this._element).one(Util.TRANSITION_END, () => {
        this._element.classList.remove(ClassName.STATIC)
      })
        .emulateTransitionEnd(modalTransitionDuration)
      this._element.focus()
    } else {
      this.hide()
    }
  }
```